# Connect ALU to CPU in Logism Circuit Design and output to 7-segment Display?

Tags: digital-logic, design, computer-architecture

I've been playing around in Logisim to get some experience in designing basic electrical circuits. While I'm sure not the best, I was able to put together a functional ALU:

**1-Bit**:
[image: 1-Bit ALU]

- This ALU is capable of the operations AND, OR, XOR, NOR, ADD/SUB.
- [A] & [B] are separately 8-bit inputs.
- The [Sub] input designates whether adding (0) or subtracting (1).
- The [Operation Setter] designates what operation is being performed.
- [R] is the result of the designated operation, with the [Zero Flag] alerting us
  to a ‘0’ output, such as when a number is subtracted from itself.

Using the 1-Bit ALU I pieced together an **8-bit ALU** (this image directly below performing an ADD operation):
[image: 8-Bit ALU]

(SUB operation):
[image: 8-Bit ALU Subtraction Operation]

[image]

I'm now attempting to take my ALU and combine it with some form of CPU (for now mainly focusing on adding/subtraction & outputting to a few 7-segment displays). I've got a 7-segment Display put together (also have another for alhpa characters AbcdEfG):

[image: 7-Segment Display (Non-Alpha)]

I can't quite figure out a good way to take what I have for an ALU and place the output into my 7-Segment Display (ultimately I want to have the result display via 3 to display all possible 255 values from my 8-bit addition):

The following is what my circuit does for each different operation:

**AND Operation - 1.1 = 1**:
[image: AND]

**OR Operation - 1+0 = 1**:
[image: OR]

**XOR Operation - 1 XOR 0 = 1**:
[image: XOR]

**NOR Operation - 1 NOR 0 = 6**:
[image: NOR]

**ADD/SUB Operationg - 1+1 = *ERROR*** (Sub Flag is errored out for all OP's??):
[image]

I'm not quite sure:

- Why my Sub Flag isn't selectable.
- Why my Zero Flag errors out on an Add/Sub Operation.
- How to fix my result from my ALU to properly go into and display in my 7-segment Display (currently outputting 8-bit into an 8-bit splitter and then placing the first 4 as my input for the 7-segment Display).

Does anyone have any input for how I can correct the issues in my design and make this work? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Sub flag issue fixed. Somehow when I brought the circuit over for use in my main one, it had the properties of being an Output, and being 3-state (which I don't believe I ever set). In any case, that minor issue is fixed.

Seems the Zero Flag was also set as 3-state for some reason.

Any advice on fixing the Add/Sub issue?

Answer (score 2):

In the last few pictures, it looks like you've configured the "sub flag" as an output, not an input. Since there's nothing driving that net, it's resulting in an error.

Comment: I'm not sure how those properties got changed, but you're right! The sub flag in my main circuit was both set as an Output & as 3-state. Thanks! Any advice on the rest?